# Get count of inner objects

Tags: php

How would you get the count of the objects inside of this object. We only want to count the two inner objects `Count This` `And This`. So our answer will be two.

Here is the object

> stdClass Object (
>
> ```
> [Count This] => stdClass Object
>     (
>         [arr] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => data
>                 [1] => some data
>             )
>     )
>
> [And This] => stdClass Object
>     (
>         [anotherArr] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => more data
>             )
>     )
> ```
>
> )

Comment: You should implement `Countable` interface for such things. Array casting might be confusing in more complex/real world case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exact answer
$total = count((array)$obj);

Comment: So thats one use for casting. Very nice.

Comment: +1 for the array casting because trying to count an object as an object returns 1 unless it implements `Countable`.

Comment: Be careful about casting if you have private, protected and public fields in your objects. This method might return different counts depending on PHP version.

Comment: @Kamil Szot: Just curious, is it possible to have private variables in a stdClass?

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
foreach($theobject as $var)
{
  if(gettype($var) == 'object')
  {
     $count++;
  }
}
```